# Output all groups and permissions throughout a SharePoint Online farm?

Tags: 2013, powershell, permissions

After a large migration I'd like to review all SharePoint groups and permissions via an algorithm but before I do I need to export them.

Is there some powershell I can run to output this throughout the farm (including cases where I have multiple nested sites)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if below Powershell command helps you:

```
Get-SPOSite | ForEach-Object {Get-SPOUser -Site $_.Url} | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-File c:\UsersReport.txt -Force -Width 360 -Append
```

Reference - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt771884.aspx

Additionally you can also have a look at this article:
https://www.andreasbijl.com/get-groups-with-users-from-sharepoint-online/

Comment: The question is about SharePoint Online.

Comment: Updated the answer